# How to get the user entered URL of a Chrome new Tab when it re-derected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I wanted to get the user given URL of the new chrome tab.
The targeted page is a SAML based authentication page, which redirects and end up at idp page.

I started with simple approaches like:
`document.referrer` which has given last referer, but not the initial url , which user entered in the URL bar.

**2nd Approach:**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
 console.log(changeInfo.url);
});
```

But for any `TabStatus` it doen't return the exact url which I expected.

**Example:**

- put this above code to a background script or enter it on the background console.
- open a new incognito window/tab and enter https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox

**console output:**

```
chrome://newtab/
https://www.google.com/intl/si/gmail/about/#
```

2nd url is the landed page's URL but not the url I entered.

My next plan is to try `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` which seems complex, but before that, I wanted to know whether is there any easy way to get this?

Comment: If the URL in the address bar changes then chrome.tabs.onUpdated is the correct solution but you may be looking at the wrong console ([How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)) or there's something else at play for which your question doesn't contain a reproducible [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm , thanks! But I tried on the background console. chrome.tabs.onUpdated is not supported in default console.

Comment: Try reading `tab.pendingUrl`.